# Multiple Counts from many INNER JOIN tables with Conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to write this query.  Here's an exmaple of the data set and what I need to query:

```
**System Table**    

SystemID   Active
1          T
2          T
3          T
4          F
5          F
6          F

**BlogPost Table**      

BlogPostID  SystemID    Create_Month
100         2           Jan
101         2           Jan
102         2           Feb
103         3           Feb
104         3           Mar
105         6           Mar
106         6           Mar

**Comment Table**       

Comment ID  BlogPostID  Liked
201         100         T
202         100         T
203         100         T
204         102         T
205         102         T
206         102         T
207         103         F
```

So, In words, I'm trying to get:  By month, show me all the active systems who created a post during that month, the number of posts they made in aggregate, and the count of the subset of those posts who had a comment that was like.

The end result would be like:

```
Column 1 - Month

Column 2 - Count of Active Systems where a Post Created in Month

Column 3 - Count of Posts Applicable to those systems

Column 4 - Count of Applicable Posts that had comments that were liked
```

I don't even know where to start really.  My terrible "this is obviously wrong" attempt is below.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
SELECT
  Month, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT system.systemid), 
  COUNT(blogpost.BlogPostID)
  COUNT(comments.commentiD)
FROM
  system INNER JOIN
  blogpost ON system.systemid = blogpost.systemid INNER JOIN
  comments ON blogpost.BlogPostID = comment.BlogPostID
WHERE
  system.active = T 
  AND comments.like = T
GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 0):

A complicated one !

```
SELECT 
b.Create_Month, 
COUNT(DISTINCT s.SystemID) as SystemCount, 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.BlogPostID) as PostsCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT t.BlogPostID) as PostsWithLike

FROM System s 

JOIN BlogPost b 
ON s.systemID = b.systemID 
AND s.Active = 'T'  

LEFT JOIN Comment c 
ON b.BlogPostID = c.BlogPostID

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT c.BlogPostID as BlogPostID
FROM 
Comment c 
GROUP BY c.BlogPostID 
HAVING SUM(if(c.Liked='T',1,0))>0
) as t
ON b.BlogPostID = t.BlogPostID

GROUP BY b.Create_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want :

```
SELECT s.systemid, active, bp.create_month, bp.systemid, COUNT(bp.blogpostid), COUNT(c.liked)
FROM system AS s 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Blogpost AS bp ON s.systemid = bp.systemid 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment AS c ON bp.blogpostid = c.blogpostid 
WHERE active = 'T' AND c.Liked = 'T' GROUP BY s.systemid,bp.create_month
```